# Can someone please explain the concept of an electrode being left "floating"?

Tags: electrode

I am looking at a stimulation system where one contact on an electrode is modeled as a Dirichlet boundary condition (the contact that is active), while the other contacts on the electrode that are inactive are left "floating." Can someone help me understand this? I understand that the active contact has a constant voltage (hence Dirichlet), but what does this mean for the other contacts? From online searches I think floating is related to the contacts being modeled as isolated or not being able to have current flow to/from them (not completely sure), but does this mean that they have a fixed voltage as well, and if so, how is that different from having them also be modeled as Dirichlet boundary conditions? Thanks in advance.

Someone asked for more technical context: I am looking at a paper on deep brain stimulation where one electrode lead has multiple contacts on it. One of the simulations involved setting all of the contacts except for one as "floating" while the active contact has a Dirichlet condition.

Comment: Please give some more information about the technical context

Comment: @Jens, I have added more context!

Comment: I'm just developing an industrial testing process for these electrodes, but I'm not deep involved in their application. As I understand, if you place a stimulus at one contact you want to see the propagation or reactions with the other contacts. They are floating, which means they measure potentials but don't inject charges or currents as the active contact does. Their measured voltages can be expressed relative to the active contact to solve further mathematical calculations or modelling.

Comment: Beautiful! This makes a lot of sense. Later on in the paper I have read that they set inactive contacts to ground and see the effect of the active contact on the electric field distribution, and then again but with the other contacts set to floating to see the sum of the effect of the active contact on the overall field (effect from the contact itself plus the effect from the contact on the other contacts). Your comment cleared up my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

A floating piece of circuit has no fixed voltage relation to the global reference potential because it is separated from it by a medium with very low conductance.

Floating describes its behavior: its voltage floats on the tide of surrounding electromagnetic radiation, the galvanic conduction, in contrast, is negligible.

If your sim includes only conduction and no radiation, then "floating" means the samr as isolated and you can ignore the floating electrode by setting the isolation material conductance to zero. The floating electrode will have a constant arbitrary potential then. If you include a slight nonzero conductance, the electrode voltage will slowly follow the mean of its surroundings.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the detailed explanation! So in the case that conductance is set to zero and the floating electrode has a constant potential, would this be the same as it having a Dirichlet condition? This is my confusion (like, how is it different from it being a Dirichlet condition setting the voltage to a constant number).

Comment: @seabass123 If I understand correctly Dirichlet as fixed boundary conditions: You can fix it at any voltage or even remove it from the sim (if you are only interested in DC behavior) and it won't change the solution. However if the medium is left with a slight conductance, then **no** boundary condition should be set for the floating electrode and its potential would result from the sim in the same way as that of the surrounding medium.